# An example of a metric space whose closed balls are never complete?

Tags: metric-spaces

At first I thought that only the empty set could possibly fit the requirement. Since if there is any element in a metric space then the set containing even only one of the element, say $a$, would have only one Cauchy sequence with its limit being $a$. Then the ball is complete. But for the empty set, there is a closed ball, namely, itself. However there is no Cauchy sequence, so nothing to check. Is it complete?　
 I also thought about the discrete metric. I can make a discrete metric space with only one point, then according to the definition there is not even a ball in it. Since for a ball $B(p,r)$, $r>0$, but in this case $r$ can only be $0$. Is this going to work?

Comment: Suppose the empty set were not complete. Then it would contain a Cauchy sequence that does not converge. Contradiction, since the empty set doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Try taking $\mathbb Q$ as your metric space.

Comment: THe empty set is always a bit hairy. Most of the times, definitions explicitly exclude the empty set to avoid having to think about pathologies. I could well imagine that many definitions of metric spaces require the underlying set to be nonempty.

Comment: A closed ball of radius $r$ about $p$ with respect to metric $d$, is $D_d(p,r)=   \{x : d(x,p)\le r$.  For a one point space $ \{p\}$ we have  $D_d(p,r)=\{p\}$ for any $ r>0$. Silvascientist's comment is  an example answer  for your main Q.